# Can someone tell me how I would modify this code to come on more than once a day?

Tags: python, timer, raspberry-pi

Can someone please tell me how I would modify this code to come on more than once a day?  I am very new to python and trying to get my pi to run this timer. I tried adding an additional variable to the array such as SatOn2 but it is ignored.  Clearly I do not understand how this works in Python. This was originally intended to run xmas lights but I am modifying to run an irrigation drip timer.

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thank You!

```
   # Raspberry Pi custom Christmas light timer

 # import GPIO module
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

 # set up GPIO pins as outputs
 # This convention is for the "P1" header pin convention
 # where the pins start with P1 in the upper left
 # and go to P26 in the lower right, with odds in the
 # left column and evens in the right column.
 # So, pins P1-11 and P1-12 correspond to GPIO17 and
 # GPIO18 respectively.
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
 GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
 GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

 # import date and time modules
 import datetime
 import time

 # Enter the times you want the lights to turn on and off for
 # each day of the week. Default is for lights to turn on at
 # 5:30pm and off at 10:30pm on weekdays, on at 5:00pm and off
 # at 11:30pm on weekends. Note that this is using a 24-hour clock.

 MonOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 MonOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 TueOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 TueOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 WedOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 WedOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 ThuOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 ThuOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 FriOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 FriOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 SatOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=0,second=0)
 SatOff = datetime.time(hour=23,minute=30,second=0)
 SunOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=0,second=0)
 SunOff = datetime.time(hour=23,minute=30,second=0)

 # Store these times in an array for easy access later.
 OnTime = [MonOn, TueOn, WedOn, ThuOn, FriOn, SatOn, SunOn]
 OffTime = [MonOff, TueOff, WedOff, ThuOff, FriOff, SatOff, SunOff]

 # Set a "wait time" in seconds. This ensures that the program pauses
 # briefly after it turns the lights on or off. Otherwise, since the
 # loop will execute more than once a second, it will try to keep
 # turning the lights on when they are already on (or off when they are
 # already off.

 waitTime = 3

 # Start the loop that will run until you stop the program or turn
 # off your Raspberry Pi.

 while True:

     # get the current time in hours, minutes and seconds
     currTime = datetime.datetime.now()
     # get the current day of the week (0=Monday, 1=Tuesday, 2=Wednesday...)
     currDay = datetime.datetime.now().weekday()

     #Check to see if it's time to turn the lights on
     if (currTime.hour - OnTime[currDay].hour == 0 and
         currTime.minute - OnTime[currDay].minute == 0 and
         currTime.second - OnTime[currDay].second == 0):

         # set the GPIO pin to HIGH, equivalent of
         # pressing the ON button on the remote
         GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)

         # wait for a very short period of time then set
         # the value to LOW, the equivalent of releasing the
         # ON button
         time.sleep(.5)
         GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)

         # wait for a few seconds so the loop doesn't come
         # back through and press the "on" button again
         # while the lights ae already on
         time.sleep(waitTime)

     #check to see if it's time to turn the lights off
     elif (currTime.hour - OffTime[currDay].hour == 0 and
         currTime.minute - OffTime[currDay].minute == 0 and
         currTime.second - OffTime[currDay].second == 0):

         # set the GPIO pin to HIGH, equivalent of
         # pressing the OFF button on the remote
         GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)

         # wait for a very short period of time then set
         # the value to LOW, the equivalent of releasing the
         # OFF button
         time.sleep(.5)
         GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)

         # wait for a few seconds so the loop doesn't come
         # back through and press the "off" button again
         # while the lights ae already off
         time.sleep(waitTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
   # Raspberry Pi custom Christmas light timer

 # import GPIO module
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

 # set up GPIO pins as outputs
 # This convention is for the "P1" header pin convention
 # where the pins start with P1 in the upper left
 # and go to P26 in the lower right, with odds in the
 # left column and evens in the right column.
 # So, pins P1-11 and P1-12 correspond to GPIO17 and
 # GPIO18 respectively.
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
 GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
 GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

 # import date and time modules
 import datetime
 import time

 # Enter the times you want the lights to turn on and off for
 # each day of the week. Default is for lights to turn on at
 # 5:30pm and off at 10:30pm on weekdays, on at 5:00pm and off
 # at 11:30pm on weekends. Note that this is using a 24-hour clock.

 MonOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 MonOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 TueOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 TueOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 WedOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 WedOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 ThuOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 ThuOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 FriOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=30,second=0)
 FriOff = datetime.time(hour=22,minute=30,second=0)
 SatOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=0,second=0)
 SatOff = datetime.time(hour=23,minute=30,second=0)
 SunOn  = datetime.time(hour=17,minute=0,second=0)
 SunOff = datetime.time(hour=23,minute=30,second=0)

 MonOnTwo  = datetime.time(hour=12,minute=30,second=0)
 MonOffTwo = datetime.time(hour=13,minute=30,second=0)

 # Store these times in an array for easy access later.
 OnTime = [[MonOn, MonOnTwo],  [TueOn], [WedOn], [ThuOn], [FriOn], [SatOn], [SunOn]]
 OffTime = [[MonOff, MonOffTwo], [TueOff], [WedOff], [ThuOff], [FriOff], [SatOff], [SunOff]]

 # Set a "wait time" in seconds. This ensures that the program pauses
 # briefly after it turns the lights on or off. Otherwise, since the
 # loop will execute more than once a second, it will try to keep
 # turning the lights on when they are already on (or off when they are
 # already off.

 waitTime = 3
 halfWait = waitTime / 2
 # Start the loop that will run until you stop the program or turn
 # off your Raspberry Pi.

 while True:

     # get the current time in hours, minutes and seconds
     currTime = datetime.datetime.now()
     # get the current day of the week (0=Monday, 1=Tuesday, 2=Wednesday...)
     currDay = datetime.datetime.now().weekday()

     for dtimes in OnTime[currDay]:

       #Check to see if it's time to turn the lights on
       if (currTime.hour - dtimes.hour == 0 and
           currTime.minute - dtimes.minute == 0 and
           currTime.second - dtimes.second > -halfWait and
           currTime.second - dtimes.second < halfWait):

           # set the GPIO pin to HIGH, equivalent of
           # pressing the ON button on the remote
           GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)

           # wait for a very short period of time then set
           # the value to LOW, the equivalent of releasing the
           # ON button
           time.sleep(.5)
           GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)


     for dtimes in OffTime[currDay]:
       #check to see if it's time to turn the lights off
       if (currTime.hour - dtimes.hour == 0 and
           currTime.minute - dtimes.minute == 0 and
           currTime.second - dtimes.second > -halfWait and
           currTime.second - dtimes.second < halfWait):

           # set the GPIO pin to HIGH, equivalent of
           # pressing the OFF button on the remote
           GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)

           # wait for a very short period of time then set
           # the value to LOW, the equivalent of releasing the
           # OFF button
           time.sleep(.5)
           GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)

     # wait for a few seconds because it's pointless to burn energy
     # with no benefit
     time.sleep(waitTime)
```